# Android UI layout for different screen size

Tags: android-layout

My UI layout designs are same for all screen size, 
so is it good to have one layout and multiple dimens.xml(based on width) file or should I have to create multiple layout files like layout-large..

Read somewhere that we have to create different layouts even if design is same and if I go with one layout and different dimens.xml, then will it work in devices like Kindle?

Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 1):

yes you have to make a separate layout for different screen sizes other wise the dimension gets small in tab and big in small device .I use [this](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)  lib

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
}
```

replace all your dp with sdp and
 if you wan more perfection [look here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)